# Localhost favicon and react errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, window, favicon

Why do I always get such errors on my localhost server even if it's completely new? I use neither react, nor favicon.  And that POST request. What's the problem, then? Is that some kind of a bug? [image]

that's my console in Opera: no react errors, no post request, only favicon
[image]

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I told you it's a completely new project. No react, no favicon, no other stuff. Just clear html file and that's it. It seems like my browser remembers my old project...

Comment: In that case, have you tried hard refreshing `ctrl + f5`

Comment: Yep, doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Check the code and make sure there's no code (press view source), something is obviously being loaded. It may also be a browser extension that's doing that, but that's very unlikely considering it's React and Sentry.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the method `indexOf` is creating problem. Are you using it on undefined variable or something?

Comment: I told you it's a completely new project. No react, no favicon, no other stuff. Just clear html file and that's it. It seems like my browser remembers my old project...